# Visual Studio 2015 Installation corruption

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and shortly after selecting a TFS server started to experience issues:

- missing package errors
- new project had no project types
- Team explorer has an error tag (Page '312e8a59-2712-48a1-863e-0ef4e67961fc' not found.)
- If I go to Team and click manage connections I get an error (Team Foundation Error Page '3185ed96-1cbcd-4381-a439-636973542e50' not found.)
- If I try to re-open the solution I pulled down I get:

  - (The 'ErrorListPackage' package did not load correctly)
  - (The 'CSharpPackage' package did not load correctly)
  - (The 'FileIndicatorPackage' package did not load correctly) and fails to open
- Then I get an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object) when I try to close VS.

I tried running the devenv.exe commands to rest everything to no avail:

```
devenv.exe /debug  
devenv.exe /resetsettings  
devenv.exe /instalvstemplates  
devenv.exe /resetskippings  
devenv.exe /resetuserdata  
devenv.exe /setup  
devenv.exe /safemode
```

I tried repair: still broken
I uninstalled and reinstalled: still broken

Answer (score 3):

**The Fix**

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2015 from Programs and Features
2. Reboot machine if prompted.
3. Rename or delete folders-

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
   - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
   - <*user>*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015
   - <*user>*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - <*user>*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - <*user>*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0
4. Go to the registry editor (start >> run >> regedit) and remove/rename the following registries-

   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Remote
5. Install Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Verified as a working solution for me.  In my case, I uninstalled Update 3 RC via Windows rollback.  It left me with the package loading problems.